# Problemas con script para visualizar y expulsar usuarios

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tkinter

estoy realizando un script con python3 en linux para que me avise de cuando alguien se a conectado a mi sistema y que me permita echar al usuario que yo quiera. Tengo este script y funciona con interfaz gráfica con la librería tkinter. El problema es que cuando voy a introducir el tty del usuario en la variable cuadronombre y le doy a enviar, el código de la funcion elimiusr no funciona `(sudo pkill -9 -t nombreusuario)`.

También e probado con: `subprocess.run("sudo pkill -9 -t {0}").format(nombreusuario)`

1.Me gustaría saber como introducir una variable de python en una orden de linux para que en este caso pueda echar al usuario.

2.También quiero saber si la forma de guardar el resultado de un Entry que yo realizo está bien. Por ejemplo:

```
cuadrotexto=Entry() 
resultadoEntry=cuadrotexto.get()
```

¿Sería así como guardar lo que pongo en el cuadro de texto en la variable resultadoEntry?

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
import subprocess
from tkinter import messagebox

a=subprocess.check_output("who|wc -l",shell=True)
b=int(a.decode("utf-8").strip())
lista=subprocess.check_output("who",shell=True)
lista2=subprocess.check_output('who| cut -d " " -f 1,4,6',shell=True)


def funelim():

  def elimiusr():

    subprocess.run("sudo pkill -9 -t nombreusuario")

 raiz=Tk()
 raiz.title("Eliminar usuario")
 raiz.resizable(0,0)
 raiz.geometry("380x150")

 texto=Label(raiz,text="Elige el tty del usuario que quieres eliminar")
 texto.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="w")

 texto2=Label(raiz,text=lista2)
 texto2.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="w",pady=10)

 cuadronombre=Entry(raiz)
 cuadronombre.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="w")
 cuadronombre.config(justify="center")
 nombreusuario=cuadronombre.get()

 boton3=Button(raiz,text="Enviar",command=elimiusr)
 boton3.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="e",padx=170)

 raiz.mainloop()


def elimus():

 if b>1:

    def exit():
        root.destroy()

    root=Tk()
    root.title("Alguien se a conectado al sistema")
    root.resizable(0,0)
    root.geometry("380x150")

    miLabel=Label(root,text="Alguien se a conectado al sistema, ¿Que quiere hacer?")
    miLabel.grid(row=0,column=0)
    miLabel2=Label(root,text=lista).grid(column=0,row=1,pady=10,sticky="w")

    boton1=Button(text="Elim.Usuario",command=funelim)
    boton1.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky="w")

    boton2=Button(text="Salir",command=exit)
    boton2.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky="e")
    root.mainloop()



  elimus()
```

Comment: Si tiene permisos, ejecuté el programa como root

Comment: Igualmente me sale error

Comment: No le estás pasando en ningún momento el nombre del usuario, `subprocess.run(["sudo", "pkill", "-9", "-t", nombreusuario])`

Comment: Como lo hago para introducir una variable de python en el comando de linux?

Comment: Cuando introduzco subprocess.run(["sudo", "pkill", "-9", "-t", nombreusuario]), en la terminal me aparece el manual de pkill

Comment: Si funciona colocando el tty directamente, el problema está en la variable, pero no sé como guardar lo que pongo en un cuadro de texto en una variable

Comment: user96431 estás obteniendo el texto una sola vez justo cuando instancias el Entry, por lo que es siempre una cadena vacía. Debes obtener el texto cuando se pulsa el botón, en la callback, esto debe funcionar: `subprocess.run(["sudo", "pkill", "-9", "-t", cuadronombre.get()])`. Otra opción es usar una StringVar asociada al Entry.

Comment: Ahora si funciona, gracias por la ayuda!